How to justify formula for area of triangle (or parallelogram)
I'm going to be teaching my kids the concept of area soon.
The concept of area of a rectangle (or square), $\text{base} \times \text{height}$ is fairly easy to both explain and intuit: you can break up the entire rectangle into unit squares (e.g. square inches, square centimeters, etc.), and then because the rectangle will have implicitly been broken up into a grid, or rows and columns, of unit squares, the total number of those unit squares is the number of unit squares along the base times the number of unit squares along the height. I.e. one can pretty naively stumble into realizing the area is $\text{base} \times \text{height}$.
Likewise, one can easily rationalize that the area of a right triangle is $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$ if you "extend" the right triangle to a full rectangle. Since the area of the rectangle is $\text{base} \times \text{height}$, if we slice that rectangle in half -- whether lengthwise, widthwise, or diagonally -- the area of each half must be $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$.
My question is about how one might justify that that formula for the area of a triangle doesn't just apply to right triangles: it applies to all triangles.
In my head, I'm imagining starting with a right triangle -- which, per above, we might reasonably infer is $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$ -- we then move the top point of the triangle left/right, so that the height is not changed, but the triangle is not a right triangle anymore. Here, I imagine that by moving the point without changing the height, in terms of the area of the triangle, "something is lost, but something is gained," and the area therefore always ends up remaining $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$. But I'm unable to articulate that in a satisfactory manner. "Something is lost, but something is gained" is too hand-wavey for my liking.
So my question, ultimately, is: is there a simple explanation (preferably one that is easily explained with little more than pictures of triangles/rectangles) why the general formula for the area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$? The target audience is an 8-year old who understands multiplication and rows/columns enough that they will easily understand that the "total" of something arranged in rows/columns is $(\text{number of rows} \times \text{number of columns})$.

Couple of points of consideration:
I realize that the general formula for the area of a triangle is derived from the area of a parallelogram, which is base × height, for which one way of justifying the formula could go like this:

Imagine a parallelogram with base $b$ and height $h$.
Imagine an "encompassing" rectangle with base $b + x$ and height $h$.
The area of the encompassing rectangle will be $(b + x) \times h = bh + xh$.
The area of the original parallelogram will be the area of the encompassing rectangle less the areas of the "excess" right triangles.
The areas of each excess triangle is $\frac{1}{2} \times x \times h$
So the total excess area is $xh$
So the area of the parallelogram is $bh + xh - xh = bh$, i.e. $\text{base} \times \text{height}$.

I note this because it's not that no explanation is within my capability, but that the above explanation is, in my opinion, a little bit more complicated than I'd like to lob at my target 8-year-olds.
My hope is that there is a simpler explanation along the lines of: "We know how to get the area of a rectangle, which is $\text{base} \times \text{height}$. So if we cut that rectangle in half diagonally, we have the area of that (right) triangle, which would then be $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$. Now, if we move the top point of the triangle left or right (i.e. without changing the $\text{height}$), that doesn't change the area from the same $\frac{1}{2} \times \text{base} \times \text{height}$ because $\{\text{explanation}\}$."

For future reference, you should not use $\ast$ for multiplication in mathematics (since it is generally reserved for either convolutions (in analysis) or a non-standard group or ring operation (in algebra).  Better to use $\times$  \times (in elementary contexts), or $\cdot$ \cdot in more advanced contexts.  Also, words like "height" or "base" which are taking the place of variables should be enclosed in a \text{} environment, as this will fix the spacing (otherwise, MathJax / TeX interprets each letter as a variable).

Rather than an encompassing rectangle, isn't it a bit easier to do a cut-and-paste operation to the parallelogram to transform it to a rectangle? There is less algebra in that case.

@Adam -- ooh, that's a clever idea, too! I hadn't thought about that! This question has generated a lot of clever answers; please feel free to expand your comment into an answer too, if you're so inclined.

Remember that this is an explanation, not a proof.

You don't need to define precisely how to construct the encompassing rectangle. Just demonstrate drawing an encompassing rectangle and have the 8-year old try to mirror it. An 8-year-old should be able to do that (perhaps with a bit of coaching) even if they can't explain to you in words what it is they're doing.
Note/Edit: you probably want to start off with acute triangles (where any side can be used as the base of an encompassing rectangle), then rotated acute triangles, then obtuse triangles (where only the longest side can be used as the base of an encompassing rectangle), then rotated obtuse triangles.

Once the kid draws the encompassing rectangle, you don't need to talk about excess triangles or whatever. Just divide the rectangle and color in the triangle as shown below so that they see how each sub-triangle covers half of its sub-rectangle. An 8-year-old will be able to understand what "half" looks like even if they can't reason formally about the area of each component piece.



(The black-and-white image is from page 4 here.)

I like this answer, but want to note that this picture only works when the height is located between the endpoints of the base.

@StevenGubkin Given a triangle, there will always be a height which lives between the endpoints (remember that a triangle has three heights).  If a triangle is drawn so that "the" height doesn't intersect a side, just rotate the triangle.

@XanderHenderson: I think that depends on your goal. If your goal is to understand that area is ½ × base × height, then you probably want to understand it even for a choice of base and height where they don't intersect.

I'd say leave it as it is and see if the eight year old comes up with the same critique!

@ruakh I see that as a feature, not a bug.  Students often struggle with the idea that orientation doesn't matter---for example, if you draw a square with horizontal and vertical sides, students will call it a square; but if you rotate it 45 degrees, they often won't recognize it as a square (they'll call it a "diamond" or something).  If you want to roughly justify the formula for the area of a triangle, choose a height which intersects a side---rotating the figure around is fine.  Once that idea is clear, it is then totally reasonable to ask if the formula depends on the choice of height.

This answer reminded me of the power of slicing a triangle into two constituent right triangles - I'd totally forgotten about making use of that!

small issue - the picture does work when the height is not located between the endpoints of the base! it just happens that you subtract the small triangle from the big triangle.

As requested, a version without the encompassing rectangle. (Or at least one that has less algebra.)
The initial triangle with base $b$ and height $h$:

Double it, to get a parallelogram with twice the area:

Cut one end (yellow) of the parallelogram off and paste on the other side (magenta) to get a rectangle with base $b$ and height $h$:

And so the area of the initial triangle is $\frac{bh}{2}$, half of the rectangle's area.
(This works for a triangle with an obtuse angle as well, but your cut for the parallelogram will go through both of the triangles.)

I do the same thing but in reverse when teaching Riemann sums in Calculus. The typical textbook motivation for definite integrals is area under the curve. I ask my students which area is the easiest, or rather the only one, that we understand intuitively. After I quickly brush off the circle with "But do you know WHY it's pi r^2?", their next response is usually a triangle, to which I similarly respond with "But WHY is it bh/2?" and tell them that triangles are still too difficult and we aren't ready for them. Then we all agree on rectangles …

… and then I do what you did here but backwards. That is, after rectangles I tell them that parallelograms have to be next, and show the same standard visual explanation. And then I tell then that we're finally mature enough for triangles, and show the same visual explanation with doubling a triangle to make a parallelogram.

If you do want to deal with a triangle whose known base has an obtuse angle at one end (so that the height is not located between the endpoints of this base), you can use subtraction.
I want the area of triangle ABC. I see that it's the area of triangle ADC minus the area of triangle BDC, both of which I know how to find.
I'll use [ABC] to mean the area of triangle ABC. (I don't know of any other simple notation for area. Art of Problem Solving uses this, and I've grown to like it.)
We have [ABC] = [ADC] - [BDC] = 1/2 x AD x DC - 1/2 x BD x DC.
The hardest part for an 8-year-old might be the distributive property, which now gives 1/2 x (AD - BD) x DC = 1/2 x AB x DC.


An alternative explanation, one formula to rule them all, so to speak:
There is a single formula that comprises the areas of a rectangle, parallelogram, trapezoid and triangle:
$\qquad$The area equals the average width times the height.
In these figures, the "average width" means half the sum of the widths at the top and bottom or the width at the midpoints of the sides, as shown by the intersections in the examples below. The width at the top of a triangle is zero.



Addenda:
Similar approach, but shows the area of a triangle is the base times half the height (figure for an acute triangle):

Somewhat more complicated if an obtuse angle is at the base:

Perhaps somewhat more challenging to deduce the area:


Another very clever way of thinking about this - I like it! In my specific case, though, I think explaining why the + sections are the same as/correspond to the - sections might require a level of knowledge of geometry perhaps a bit advanced for my target 8-year-old audience.

@StoneThrow Thanks. Is it not obvious that all the sides of the triangles in +/- pair have the same length? Each corresponding pair can be seen as half of the same thing: half the side, half the height, the most difficult one being the horizontal lengths are half the horizontal width of one of the sides. Or another way: A half turn switches each +/- pair, one triangle into the other. In either way, wouldn't an 8-year-old see them as the same triangle, the other the same as the one turned halfway around its vertex? Yet again: Get some paper and scissors and have the kids explore.

took me a little while to orient myself to your thinking, and on reevaluation, agreed, it's actually clear. My kids are smarter than me, so maybe they'll realize the fact quicker than I did! :)

I do recommend going through the rectangles and parallelograms, but I just want to note that your intuition about starting with a right triangle and moving the top around is Cavalieri's principle and an important idea in mathematical analysis.
You can demonstrate it easily - take a straight heap of coins (playing cards, notebooks, whatever), and then move them a bit to the side. The volume (and the visible surface area when seen from the side) obviously remain unchanged.
This is also what happens with the triangle and you can even measure it with a ruler, by drawing too triangles with the same base and height, and then checking that the horizontal slices at any given height are equally long.
No guarantees that the entire chain of reasoning here is comprehensible to a given person.
